# How to get the root DOM element of an el-popover component in Element-Plus?

Tags: vue.js, element-plus

I'm using the el-popover component from Element-Plus in my Vue project to create a popover effect. Here's the code:

```
<el-button ref="saveButtonRef" class="misc-button" :loading="saveLoading" @click="OnSheetSave">Save</el-button>
<el-popover ref="savePopoverRef" :virtual-ref="saveButtonRef" :visible="showSaveList" placement="top-start" :width="500" virtual-triggering>
   ...el-popover Content...
</el-popover>
```

I want the popover to close when the mouse clicks outside of both the saveButtonRef and savePopoverRef instances. Therefore, I added an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener('click', handleClickPopoverOutside);

function handleClickPopoverOutside(event) {
    if (showSaveList.value) {
        const buttonElement = saveButtonRef.value.$el;
        const popoverElement = savePopoverRef.value.$el;
        if (buttonElement && !buttonElement.contains(event.target) && popoverElement && !popoverElement.contains(event.target)) {
            OnSaveSheetPoPoverClose();     // Close Popover Instance
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work as expected. When I click on the savePopoverRef instance, it still triggers the OnSaveSheetPoPoverClose() function. I found that the reason is because savePopoverRef.value.$el returns #text. Is there a way to properly get the root DOM element of the el-popover component, or is there another approach to close the popover when clicking outside of it?

As mentioned above, I want to be able to close the popover by triggering my function OnSaveSheetPoPoverClose() when clicking outside of the saveButtonRef and savePopoverRef instances. And I don't want to change the virtual-ref of savePopoverRef from saveButtonRef, as it would affect my other logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For hiding a popup programmatically in Vue, I take a reverse approach to handling the events. It is easier and more general.

1. Listen to click event globally (on the window object) by `window.addEventListener`
2. Stop the button and the popup events by `@click.stop`

This way, I can catch the click events that occur outside of the popup, while letting popup content do and process their click event.

Here is a sample demo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/element-plus/dist/index.css" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-plus"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <el-button 
    class="misc-button"
    @click.stop="toggleDialog"
    >
    Show Dialog
    </el-button>
    
    <el-button 
    ref="saveButtonRef"
    class="misc-button"
    :loading="saveLoading"
    @click.stop="OnSheetSave"
    >
    Save
    </el-button>

    <el-popover 
    :visible="showSaveList"
    placement="top-start" 
    :width="300"
    virtual-triggering
    >
      <div style="min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px;border: 1px dashed red;" @click.stop>
        Your pop-up content goes here. Clicking anywhere on the popup won't close the modal, but clicking outside triggers the event handler and closes the modal
      </div>
    </el-popover>

  </div>
  <script>
    const App = {
      data() {
        return {
          showSaveList: false,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        OnSaveSheetPoPoverClose() {
         console.log('OnSaveSheetPoPoverClose got called');
         this.toggleDialog(); // hide dialog and remove the event listener
         this.OnSheetSave();
        },
        
        OnSheetSave(){
          console.log('OnSheetSave got called');
        },
        
        toggleDialog() {
          if (this.showSaveList) {
              this.showSaveList = false;
              window.removeEventListener('click', this.OnSaveSheetPoPoverClose);
          } else {
             this.showSaveList = true;
             window.addEventListener('click', this.OnSaveSheetPoPoverClose);
          }
        },    
      },     
    };
    const app = Vue.createApp(App);
    app.use(ElementPlus);
    app.mount("#app");
        
  </script>
</body>
```

#### Explanation

There is a `Show Dialog` button, which shows the popup and adds the event listener ensuring the `OnSaveSheetPoPoverClose` gets called on every click.

To prevent common elements from triggering the `OnSaveSheetPoPoverClose`, I stopped their click event (prevent it from propagating) using `@click.stop`.

### Note

Make sure to remove event listeners at the proper time.